# Load-testing a web application

Tags: performance

How does one go about testing the server-side performance of a web application?

I'm working on a small web application (specifically, it will solely be responding to AJAX requests with database rows). I want to see how it performs under load. However, I cannot upload it to an internet host right away. The development environment is, however, part of the local intranet, so I can use as many machines as I want to hammer the development server, presumably using Python in conjunction with urllib2.

My question is, is such an approach really accurate for determining the high-load performance of a server-side script? Is there a better way to do this? Am I missing something here?

Comment: What is the technology you're using?

Comment: PHP, though I might migrate to Python if it doesn't deliver.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a tool like Apache JMeter?  http://jmeter.apache.org/